# Difference between SenderFaultCode and ReceiverFaultCode

Tags: web-services, wcf

what's the main difference between **SenderFaultCode** and **ReceiverFaultCode**. With WCF's **FaultExceptions**, we can create a **FaultCode** with two methods :

- CreateSenderFaultCode.
- CreateReceiverFaultCode.

In which case should we use one or the other ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SenderFaultCode: Represents the [SOAP version 1.2] Sender fault code indicating a client call was not formatted correctly or did not contain the appropriate information.

ReceiverFaultCode: Represents the [SOAP version 1.2] Receiver fault code indicating an error occurred during the processing of a client call on the server due to a problem with the recipient.

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.protocols.soap12faultcodes?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thank you ! It's well explained